# Getting a 403 Forbidden error - Unable to install a specific package hosted on a nexus server

Tags: yarnpkg, nexus

I'm trying to add a package hosted on a Nexus server of my project customer. All packages are installed using Yarn, but I'm encountering a problem with a specific package from FontAwesome. Whenever I try to install it, I receive a "403 Forbidden" error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: "https://nexus.customer/repository/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/-/fontawesome-pro-6.4.0.tgz: Request failed \"403 Forbidden\"".
```

I'm connected to a VPN, and I have disabled the rebind protection for the company's domain in my FritzBox router (exception added).

I'm wondering what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it. Unfortunately, we haven't been able to find a solution so far.